# How do you say the noun form of "Campaign"

Tags: vocabulary

I know that in Chinese we can say "竞选” for campaigning （as in a verb). But, if I wanted to say "campaign" as in "Obama's Campaign" how would I say that? I've seen 竞选活动 in dictionaries。 But， would people say  奥巴马的“竞选活动“？

Comment: Yes, we do say `奥巴马的竞选活动`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use 竞选 as noun in your case. 在这次奥巴马的竞选中。The local media prefer using 竞选 than 竞选活动 though both are okay.

Comment: But what I am referring to the physical campaign? Like the team? Could I say something like 

奥巴马这次的竞选很厉害？

Comment: No. If you mean a team, say 竞选团队。

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say  奥巴马的竞选活动.

竞选活动 is referred to the activities in lie to some competitions like elections.

this is an example from **dict.cn**

1. 在明年的重选中她参加"竞选"。
   She comes up for **re-election** next year.
2. 他在"总统竞选"中曾以改革者的姿态出现
   He have project himself as a reformer in the **presidential campaign**.
3. 有人说布什因选举大会开得不好以及"竞选"方法不佳而受害。可是即使两者都做得较好，结果也将是一样。我想根本问题也不在于经济。
   Some will say Mr. Bush was done in by a bad convention and a bad **campaign**. But if both had gone better the outcome would have been the same. And I don't think it all came down to the economy, either.
4. 他将参加"总统竞选"。
   He'll run for the **Presidency**.

Answer (score 1):

奥巴马的 “竞选活动“ should be good.

The other one people might say is "造势活动", which literally means "build power activity"